# Как вызвать функцию в компоненте из другого компонента?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, функции, компоненты

как вызвать функцию в компоненте по onClick из другого? Я набросал примитивный пример, разумеется, в данном примере можно всё перенести в один компонент, но на реальном проекте мне нужно, чтобы функция changeData выполнилась в отдельном компоненте.
В интернете нашёл инструкцию только по классовым компонентам.
[Ссылка на CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-meadow-5wm3n)

Comment: https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/how-to-pass-data-between-react-components

Comment: Вы можете использовать обьект action=onClick()